# PHP built a select input from array is not working properly ... sometimes

Tags: php, arrays, select, input

OK, so i recently added the $ignored and $NoneText pars, and tested it OK, then i had a situation where `echo select_site(4,6,'');` ignores correctly, but the selected attribute doesn't work.

```
function select_site($selected = '', $ignored = '', $NoneText = '') {
    GLOBAL $IsActive, $dbcnx;
    @$SiteArray = prepared_site_select();
        $select= '<select name="SelectContacts">'.
                '<option value="0">None '.$NoneText.'</option>';
        while (list ($key, $row) = each ($SiteArray) ){
            if($row['ndx'] == $ignored) {
                $selected = '';
            } elseif($row['ndx'] == $selected){
                $select.='<option value="'.$row['ndx'].'" selected>'.$row['SiteName'].'</option>';
            } else {
                $select.='<option value="'.$row['ndx'].'">'.$row['SiteName'].'</option>';
            }
        }
//      endwhile;
        $select.='</select>';
return $select;
}
```

I have tried reversing the If/ElseIf around and that did no good ... where has my logic gone wrong ?

$SiteArray contains the following after it gets populated by prepared_site_select():

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ndx] => 6
            [SiteNDX] => 6
            [IsActive] => 1
            [SiteParent] => 4
            [ChildCount] => 0
            [ProjectCount] => 1
            [TaskCount] => 1
            [SiteName] => SHB
            [SiteAddress] => Lower Fort Street, Sydney, NSW, Aus
            [SiteDescription] => Sydney Harbour Bridge
            [SiteContact] => 5
            [SitePassword] => 
            [Created] => 2018-04-28 00:42:50
            [Updated] => 2018-04-28 10:15:33
            [NameFirst] => Ray
            [NameLast] => Little
            [ContactsIsActive] => 1
            [ParentName] => SOH
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ndx] => 4
            [SiteNDX] => 4
            [IsActive] => 1
            [SiteParent] => 
            [ChildCount] => 2
            [ProjectCount] => 3
            [TaskCount] => 2
            [SiteName] => SOH
            [SiteAddress] => 2 Macquarie Street Sydney
            [SiteDescription] => Sydney Opera House
            [SiteContact] => 8
            [SitePassword] => 
            [Created] => 2018-04-23 23:17:12
            [Updated] => 2018-04-23 23:17:12
            [NameFirst] => James
            [NameLast] => Dolby
            [ContactsIsActive] => 1
            [ParentName] => 
        )

)
```

If anyone can point out what i did wrong, i would be grateful as i have a few of these on a site that is soon to go live and its really annoying me that i cannot figure it out (im sure its simple ... but i can't see the forest through the trees)

This is the output without $ignored:

```
<select name="SelectContacts"><option value="0">None (test)</option><option value="6">SHB</option><option value="4" selected>SOH</option></select>
```

This is with ignored:

```
<select name="SelectContacts"><option value="0">None (test)</option><option value="4">SOH</option></select>
```

Comment: could you provide HTML-code of the result, please?

Comment: give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear how the `$ignore` parameter plays into this as it looks like either something is selected or it isn't. If that's the case this would work and be easier to read and understand IMO.

```
while (list ($key, $row) = each ($SiteArray) ){

    if ($row['ndx'] == $ignored) {continue;}

    $select .='<option value="'.$row['ndx'].'"';
    $select .= ($row['ndx'] == $selected ? ' selected' : '');
    $select .= '>'.$row['SiteName'].'</option>';
}  // endwhile;
```

Comment: thanks dave, i will try your code and see if that makes a difference ... there is no logic to it that i can see ... thought it must have just been me.

Comment: Note that I have not referenced your `$ignored` parameter as I could not discern any use for it. From your description something will either be selected or it won't be.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, the `$ignored ` removed the option from the select all together ... thus ignoring or removing that item from the select list. I will play with your code for a bit and see if i can get ignored to work in an if inside the while ...

Comment: Thanks @Dave, your solution worked ... and more eligant than any of my hacks ... but hey, i haven't really coded in PHP in 20 odd years and then i was just a hack, so thats probably why ... thanks anyway Dave